# Is creating separate support class for logging relevant?

Tags: java, logging

I'm working on project that connects to remote API.
In case response is not ok (e.g. there is status TOO_MANY_REQUESTS) I'd like to log data.
With just adding code to fetching method e.g.

```
logger.debug("example");
```

I could provide logging functionality however I may face an issue with testing it.
Is creating additional support class with methods providing functionality to add logs relevant in such case or is there different approach?

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: @shmosel I currently use JUnit

Comment: Why don't you just use one of the many logging frameworks out there?